# Parsing HTML content of sign-in protected page

Tags: python, parsing, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

Is it possible to parse HTML content of sign-in protected page?

Like this page - https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/members/coravh-201/

Quick code to test:

```
import urllib2
address = 'https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/members/coravh-201/'
website = urllib2.urlopen(address)
website_html = website.read()
```

Comment: yes, if you have valid user credentials. Or you just want to get `html` of authorization page?

Comment: @Andersson: I want actual page content. What is the way if I have user credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get content of webpage you can simply use `pyrequests` module:

```
import requests
requests.get('https://username:password@www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/members/coravh-201/').content
```

To install `pyrequests` module use `pip install requests` in your shell